# .Net Web Api возвращает пустой запрос при выборке из бд

Tags: c#, mysql, json, asp.net-web-api

Здравствуйте проблема заключается в том что если делаю выборку из БД используя вот такую функцию

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("people")]
[ResponseType(typeof(People))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllWorker()
{
    List<People> data = await db.People.Where(c => c.Class.Contains("Работник")).ToListAsync();
    return Json(data);
}
```

В итоге возвращается мне пустой ответ [], но если я в БД заменю "Работник" на "Worker" то поменяв тоже самое слово в функции то я получу нужную выборку из БД в формате Json. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? Через консоль mysql выборка русскими буквами проходит хорошо, через sql запрос в phpmyadmin тоже все хорошо, в а web api .net не получается (пробовал и через браузер и через Fiddler), хотя кажется раньше всё работало (функцию сделал давно и к ней не возвращался но она вроде бы работала, т.е выбирала русские буквы из БД), не так давно обновил MariaDB на сервере, может с этим связано как то.

Comment: Возможно изменилась кодировка в базе, попробуйте проверить

Comment: Уберите `Where` и гляньте, что в `List<People> data`, будет ли там `Class` содержать "Работник".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, если запрашиваю всех People в графе ответа есть строка Class: работник, но чисто по Class возвращает [] но я вспомнил что ДО обновы mariadb 100% всё работало.

Comment: @dmepty Возможно, а как посмотреть кодировку точнее? в phpmyadmin на против таблиц БД написано  utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: `в графе ответа есть строка Class: работник` - так `Работник` или `работник`? Это две разные вещи...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ когда вызываю всех people в графе Class "Работник" написано, точь в точь как и в базе данных, даже менял специально в БД и сразу запрашивал, ну вместо работника просто ударил по клаве "овыалор" и всё так же хорошо вывелось в общей выборке, но вот чисто Class с where он присылает в ответ [] что за магия такая...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в обновлении MariaDB сервера. Скопировал из бекапа прошлой версии файл "my.cnf" перезапустил сервис mysql, и web api нормально стал отдавать ответы где выборка из бд идет русскими буквами. Уж не знаю в чем конкретно была проблема в файле, но теперь всё работает.

P.S - Так же помогает исправить ошибку добавление в Web.config ВебАпи, в строчку подключения к бд charset, строчка будет выглядеть вот таким образом:

```
<add name="MyConnection" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="User ID=root;Password=myAwesomePass;Host=localhost;Database=myDB;charset=utf8" />
```

**Стаковерфлоу, спасибо за подсказку в комментариях.**